# How to get rid of an exception "IOException: File '... ... ... .pdf' cannot be written to"

Tags: android, file, ioexception

I want to download a PDF-file from the link and open it in the pdf-reader. For this I indicated:

- in the manifesto:

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  ```
- in the class AppAsyncTasks.java:

  ```
  public static class FileLoadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, File> {

      private static final String LOG_TAG = "FileLoadingTask";

      public FileLoadingTask(final Context cxt,
                             final JSONOrder order,
                             final FileLoadingListener listener) {

      }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();
          createPdLoading(pdLoading);
          this.url = mOrder.getPreviewlink();
          this.extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
          this.folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "Download");
          this.folder.mkdir();
          this.fileName = mOrder.getOrdercode() + ".pdf";
          this.file = new File(this.folder, this.fileName);
          fileLoadingListener.onBegin();
      }

      @Override
      protected File doInBackground(Void... params) {
          try {
              FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(url), file);
          } catch (IOException e) {        
              throwable = e;
          }
          return file;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(File file) {
          super.onPostExecute(file);
          pdLoading.dismiss();
          fileLoadingListener.onEnd(file);
          if (throwable != null) {
              fileLoadingListener.onFailure(throwable);
          } else {
              fileLoadingListener.onSuccess();
          }
      }            
      public interface FileLoadingListener {

          void onBegin();               
          void onSuccess();              
          void onFailure(Throwable cause);                
          void onEnd(File file);                
      }
  }
  ```

However, writing a file to the internal media does not happen - an exception is thrown:

> IOException: File 'storage/emulated/0/Download/...pdf' cannot be written to

How to get rid of this exception?

Comment: Add sufficient code . You pdf write method is missing .and post the whole crash log .

Comment: 1) post your full error log  . 2) don't forget to get  permission at runtime also .

Comment: also don't forget to add Android N permission via file providers before downloading the content to destination directory.

Comment: This exception does not fall into the error log, because it is processed further by outputting a digalog box with a message about it. But at the expense of permitting checks - this is a good topic. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is workable. I included in the code instructions for checking the write permission to external memory. As suggested by [Tejas Pandya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6880611/tejas-pandya) and [Dhaval Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5518993/dhaval-patel).

To do this, my onPreExecute () method is added as follows:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            while (checkPermissions()) {
            }
        }
        createPdLoading(pdLoading);
        ... ... ... ... ...
    }
```

The method checkPermissions() returns the value "true" if there is no permission to write files to external memory, and - "false", if any.

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        switch (App.getCurFragContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            case PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                fileLoadingListener.requestPermissions();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

I added a requestPermissions() method  to FileLoadingListener interface. It is called from checkPermissions() method and has the following implementation:

```
    @Override
    public void requestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                (Activity) mActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                App.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE);
    }
```